# Spring-kafka - Message loss with AckMode Record and custom SeekToCurrent error handler

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with **transient errors** that occur in the message listener while **consuming messages** from a Kafka topic. 
I'm using a **@KafkaListener** configured with a **custom errorHandler**. When the **listener throws** and Exception and the errorHandler considers it **transient**, the handler **seeks** the client to the **current offset** in order to re-fetch the message on next poll.

The listener receives the message in loop waiting for the transient issue to be resolved, as expected, but in some circumstances messages were **lost**.

I'm using spring-kafka 2.2.5, please see spring boot relevant configuration for Kafka

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: <HOST>:<PORT>
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      enable-auto-commit: false
      group-id: ConsumerGroup
      properties:
        max.poll.records: 1
    listener:
      ack-mode: record
      concurrency: 1
```

As far as I can see the application lose messages in the following cases:

- An exception not initiated/handled by the message listener error handler is propagated to the **KafkaMessageListenerContainer**. The default value for the container property **ackOnError** is true so the container commits the offset. If the listener is restarted the message is not processed anymore by any other client in the consumer group as the offset has been already committed and moved forward;
- No exception/error is propagated to container but the listener is restarted in the middle of the transient error processing loop described before. As in the previous case, clients in the consumer group will not reconsume the message as the offset has been committed by the container during the first poll.

So in order to fix the first issue it should be enough to set ackOnError to false. But for the second issue I started wondering if AckMode record is proper in this scenario because the message is committed in every case.

Should I move to MANUAL_IMMEDIATE in this scenario or am I missing the point here?

Many thanks, kind regards

Answer (score 0):

`ackOnError` has been false by default since version 2.3; it has been deprecated since 2.4 (in favor of `GenericErrorHandler.isAckAfterHandle()`) and is removed on master (the future 2.7).

> as the offset has been committed by the container during the first poll.

I am not sure what you mean by that. If you are referring to the logic in the rebalance listener, if the listener is restarted you'll get a new consumer so it's `position()` will be the last committed offset.

Starting with version 2.3.6 you can completely disable that logic by setting the `assignmentCommitOption` to `NEVER`.

2.2.x is end of life (along with Boot 2.1) and will get no more releases. The last 2.2.x version was 2.2.14. 2.2.5 is nearly 2 years old; you should try to keep more up-to-date.

The latest release is 2.6.3.

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer!
Migration to 2.6.3 is on his way :)
With the sentence "as the offset has been committed by the container during the first poll" I mean that I've stepped into KafkaMessageListenerContainer code and seen that, when using AckMode RECORD, the container commits the offsets in any case. So my @KafkaListener errorHandler is catching exceptions and repositioning partition offsets in order to fetch again failed messages on next poll but at the same time the container commits and this causes the loss when the client is rebalanced or restarted.

Comment: the custom listener errorHandler is committing offsets when there is an Acknowledgment in the message headers but in the case described the error handler is just repositioning offsets in case of errors and the container is expected to commit as we are using AckMode.RECORD. The listener errorHandler is catching all exceptions and never throws them again and this is causing offset commit even when the message processing keeps failing. What do you think about this?

Comment: If the error handler doesn't throw an exception, the error is considered "handled" and the container moves on to the next record. If you perform seeks, the error handler must be a `RemainingRecordsErrorHandler` and seeks must be performed for all partitions for remaining records in the batch. Why do you need a custom error handler? The provided STCEH should be sufficient, if not, most people subclass it to add more functionality. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek-to-current A lot of functionality has been added to it in recent versions.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks again for helping! The error handler I'm using is at listener level. `@KafkaListener` uses a `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` interface bean, it is not an `ErrorHandler` like the one you mentioned. 
As far as I understood `RemainingRecordsErrorHandler`  is a container level error handler. I checked spring-kafka 2.6.3 code and the KafkaMessageListenerContainer is calling `isAckAfterHandle()` only on the container errorHandler so it would not fix my issue. So it looks to me that if the listener error handler does not throw, the message is always committed both in 2.2.5 and 2.6.3.

Comment: Oh - no; listener error handlers can't do low-level stuff like seeking; that must be done at the container level. Listener level error handlers are intended for higher level situations, such as returning a different result (in a request/reply scenario) when an exception is thrown. I can see, however that the javadocs imply that you can; I need to fix that.

Comment: ah ok I've just seen your last reply! So we are trying to achive something that the listener error handler is not designed/intended for ok.Yeah probably a mix of java doc and the technical capability to seek in the listener container error handler lead to the current situation. Ok many many thanks.